# Trying to use function in a react stateless class component

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to build a react app for weather. I am using openweathermap api.
i have a component that supposed to render 5 weather components, each one for each day (it's a 5 day forecast).
however, something is not working.
this is the weather component:

```
class Weather extends Component{

getAllDates = () =>{
    const list = this.props.list;
    let date = list[0]["dt_txt"].split(" ")[0];
    const datesList = [{date: date, indexes: [0]}];
    let indexes = [];
    for(let i = 1; i < list.length; i++){
        const currDate = list[i]["dt_txt"].split(" ")[0];
        if(date !== currDate){
            datesList.push({
                date: currDate,
                indexes: indexes});
            date = currDate;
            indexes = [];
        }
        else{
            const toUpdate = datesList.pop();
            const oldIndexes = toUpdate.indexes;
            const newIndexes = oldIndexes.push(i);
            toUpdate.indexes = newIndexes;
            datesList.push(toUpdate);
        }
    }
    return datesList;
}  

    render(){
        const datesList = this.getAllDates();
        return(
            <React.Fragment>
              {datesList.map((date, key) => {
                  return <DayWeather date = {date} 
                              key = {key}
                              forecastList = {this.props.list} />
              })}
            </React.Fragment>
        )

    }
```

and in App.js I am rendering it conditionally like this:

```
{this.state.data === undefined ? <h1>Choose City</h1> :
   <Weather list = {this.state.data.list}/>}
```

The problem is, the getAllDates is called twice from the render function in Weather component.
the loop goes for 2 iterations instead of 40, and then getAllDates is called again. I can't understand why because I have conditional rendering in App.js.
Also, the indexes variable at some point turns into a number and not an array,
and then I get an error that I can't do .push to indexes.

I have no idea what is hapenning here,
would appreciate any kind of help!
thank you!

**here I am fetching the data:

```
class App extends Component{
  constructor(){
    super();
    this.state = {
      data: undefined
    }

  }

  onSelectHandler = (event) =>{
    const city = event.target.value;
    const apiCall = `http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?q=${city},il&APPID=${API_KEY}`
    fetch(apiCall)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(response => 
    {
      this.setState({
        data: response
      })
    }
  )

  }
```

Comment: It'd be helpful to see where you're setting the `list` state as well

Comment: Can you add it to the post instead of a comment? Thanks!

Comment: yeah I added it :)

Comment: any chance the `onSelectHandler` is running twice? You could try console logging/counting at the top of that method just to check.

Comment: Or, of course, you could just check the network requests in your console to see if you're requesting the data twice

Comment: I console logged from there, it printed once

Comment: Hmm, nothing is jumping out at me. It'd be helpful to see the code in full; any chance you can create a codesandbox or something with the code? Rather than doing an actual API query you can just return some sample data

Comment: what does `console.log(this.props.list.length)` in your Weather component say?

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/zealous-hopper-v1h9l?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

azium, it says 40

Comment: I think the problem is with this line :
const oldIndexes = toUpdate.indexes;
I tried to console log toUpdate and it was ok and didnt render twice.
when I tried to console log toUpdate.indexes or toUpdate.date or even toUpdate.length, it renders twice. Why??

Comment: Ok, the problem was with the push. I thought that array.push returns a new array but it returns the length of the array. I don't know why it made React render twice but after I fixed the problem it renders one time now. Thank you!